# Get output from muterun_js to python

Tags: javascript, python

I am using Naked.toolshed.shell to execute javascript with python.
https://naked.readthedocs.io/toolshed_shell.html#javascript-node-js-execution-functions

The python code is like this.

```
def push_transaction(self, ...):
        """
        node PushContractTransaction.js  [...]
        """
        arguments = [...]
        )
        response = muterun_js(self.current_dir + '/js/PushContractTransaction.js', arguments=arguments)
        if response.exitcode == 0:
            print(f"This is the response: {response}")
            return
        else:
            raise PushContractTransactionException(response.stderr)
```

The javascript code that is called returns a string.
Now i want this string in python. I am getting this object as a reponse, but I don't know how to extract the return value from it.

> Naked.toolshed.types.NakedObject object at 0x105a84390

I could log something to console and then use response.stderr but doesn't seem like a good solution and I think there is a much easier one.

Comment: So the JS code has a function that retruns the string or is it just a script that computes the string and stores it in a variable then exits?

Comment: The function does some stuff (using a js library to call an api) and then returns a string

Comment: if you do `print(dir(response))` You will notice there are a lot of attributes, but none which contain anything related to the local scope / variables in the local scope of the JS file, so you can't get a variable / function's return value from the response object

Comment: Also using `response.stdout.decode("utf-8")` / `response.stderr.decode("utf-8")` is a pretty simple one liner? Do you have any certain objection to it? Or is just that you want a "cleaner" solution?

Comment: I don't have a clear objection, I just thought there is a cleaner solution, because I would not log in JS and instead I return something :)

Comment: maybe you could use a different module that gives you access to the local scope? I've looked on the internet but can't seem to find anything like that. You could also write the string to a file and then read it in python... Just a few suggestions

Comment: Yes, seems like this one is the way to go. Well not a big deal for me, just wondered if I could do it a bit more elegant. writing to a file would also be possible of course. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Making it into an answer:

`muterun_js` returns a `Naked` object which has an `stdout` attribute for standard output stream data, a `stderr` attribute for standard error stream data, and an `exitcode` attribute for the exit code.

Getting output of javascript script:

```
naked_object = muterun_js('script.js')
print("Output", naked_object.stdout.decode("utf-8"))
```